# Is it necessary to create an ACS with Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, active-directory, oauth-2.0

Is it required that I create my own Azure ACS if I want to use the Active Directory? Am I able to simply create a new application instance on the Active Directory Pane (on the Azure Management Console) without having an ACS to build on? I don't want to need to pay to create my own ACS niche.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're talking about creating an "Access Control Namespace".

It actually isn't necessary to do so. You can register an application with Azure AD without having an ACN "niche" - having an ACN is something that is generally better for larger enterprise applications or those that have to handle requests on many different levels (with many different applications). So unless you're building something very large, there's no reason to set an ACN up on the Management Console (and you can continue to use everything for free with the AD functionality without an ACN). Hope this helps.

Comment: Also ACS is deprecated and it's functionality is being merged into AAD. http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2013/06/22/azure-active-directory-is-the-future-of-acs.aspx